# Unable to use Curiosity HPC on MPLABX (PKOB), how can I get it to work on current IDE?

Tags: pic, mplab, pic18

I've just installed **MPLAB X IDE v5.30** on my computer, connected a Curiosity HPC development board, which has an integrated programmer (PICkit-on-board, PKOB), and tried to use it on a project, however, on the project settings menu, the board is detected and listed under "Starter kits (PKOB)" *but* shows as unsupported (like the venerable PICkit2)

*Has microchip discontinued this product or is it some sort of configuration error? How can I solve it?*

Project is using a `PIC18F23K22` microcontroller, and the compiler is XC8 (free).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After running it through **MPLAB IPE v5.20** once, by selecting the microcontroller and clicking "Apply" then "Connect" the IPE tool updated the board firmware from **01.51.07** to **01.56.00**.

**IPE v5.20 (old) output:**

[image: Update process]

Once completed, the tool is detected by IPE version **v5.30** without any apparent issue, even updating it to firmware revision **01.56.02**. At this point the tool is detected no issue by the IDE as well.